# Get a compiled variable value from a xslt file

Tags: c#, xml, csv, xslt-1.0

Hellu

I'm trying to make a little program which goal is too convert files to another format. To this end, I use some external xslt files, and XslCompilerTransformer in a C# project.

I want my XSLT files to contain a filepath in which the result of the transformation would be saved. This path would be generated from values retrieved inside the file to be transformed, and looks like this:

```
<xsl:param name="path" select="'C:\mypath\'"/>
<xsl:param name="file" select="'[/HISTORY/@file]-[/HISTORY/@data]'"/>
```

So the "file" parameter will have this value retrieved from the attributes "file" and "data" from the node HISTORY.

I hardly think that there is a way to get the compiled value of this parameter inside the C# program.

**So I guess I have to put this value inside the transformed file one way or another, but since this file could be XML or CSV (or else, who knows!), I have no idea of how I could do that.**

Do you? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *compiled*? Do you rather mean the transformed value, that is, the resulting value in the XML output? I think you would be able to retrieve the value from the resulting XML document by doing an XSLT transformation into a memory stream and then applying an XPath expression on it. However, it may be easier to extract the required values from the input XML directly using XPath and then doing the required postprocessing there. One more remark: in your second select you are using single quotes. This will prevent the expression in the quotes from being *compiled*.

Comment: Continued: you should rather use `select="concat('[', /HISTORY/@file, ']-[', /HISTORY/@data, ']')"`.

Comment: @Marcus Yeah, I had hard times with those quotes. 'it may be easier to extract the required values from the input XML directly using XPath and then doing the required postprocessing there' => my thought as well, after giving it more research. I will just go for another xslt that will perform before the first one to compile the value, leaving the result not polluted with this extra unneeded informations. Thanks